# Python string formatting creating a random new line on print statement

Tags: python, string, io, formatting, line

Here is my function.  Trying to get this all to print to one line.

Here is the output ->

```
config::$var['pdf']['meta']['staff_member_name']
 = ";"
```

The `= ";"` portion of the string prints to a new line in the console for some reason?

This is totally just a personal hack to help with a repetitious job requirement so i'm not looking for anything fancy.

Here is my function ->

```
def auto_pdf_config(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        kill = " = array("
        start = "config::$var['intake']"
        new_line = ""
        for line in content:
            if kill not in line:
                pass
            elif start in line:
                new_line = line
                x = new_line.replace(kill, "")
                y = x.replace(start,"")
                pdf_end = ' = ";" '
                z = "config::$var['pdf']['meta']{}{}".format(y,pdf_end)
                print(z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you "y" variable has new line in it. you can try to strip it off.

```
y = x.replace(start,"").strip('\n')
```

Comment: more generally, every `line`, with the exception of the last, will have a `\n` at the end when you're going through a file. Also, the basic `strip()` will take newlines (along with any other whitespace, which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: Thank you very much!  New to python and missed this method.  Worked like a charm

Comment: @Willy happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Since x = new_line.replace(kill, ""), y = x.replace(start,""), and new_line is the line of content, it contains endline symbol (\n), that's why this endline symbol is appended before pdf_end. You just need to remove endline symbol from y.
You can do something like that:

```
y = y.strip('\n')
```